# Cosmos DB SQL Indexing Policy, how to index only specific properties?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Say you have a document with lots of properties, and you only want to index some, for example property1

```
{
  "id": "AndersenFamily",
  "partitionKey": "a",
  "property1": "b",
  "property2": "c",
  ...
  "property100": "x",
}
```

I tried something like the policy bellow, but then just got errors from the .net core client api saying I were querying non-index fields..

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/property1/?",
            "indexes": [                    
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
       {
         "path". "/*"
       }
    ]
}
```

What I am trying to do is say that no properties are to be indexed, unless specified explicitly in the includedPaths. How to do that?

Also, would I in this case need to configure indexing for partition key and id in the policy, or does that happen automatically?

Comment: What property did you try querying? If it's not the ones specified in your index policy (in your case, `property1`), you'd get an error unless you forcibly enabled a scan.

Comment: I believe it was one of the indexed ones, but I might have been mistaken based on what you say. But if that is the case, you are saying the policy should work just fine?